# Constructing NxN tridiagonal block diagonal matrix with N is a variable

Tags: matrix, numerics, linear-algebra, physics, quantum-computing

Hi please can someone help me writing a program of generating a tridiagonal block matrix with dimension of NxN where N is a variable can be 50, 100, 200, 300...etc , Well I don't know how I'm a beginner. THANK YOU ANYWAY!

My matrix is in the photos [image]

[image]

Comment: You can get a diagonal matrix with `IdentityMatrix[n]`. For the rest, improve your question and formatting.

Comment: If you search the built-in help center for "tridiagonal", the first hit shows how and points you to `SparseArray`, whose documentation page also shows how to construct a tridiagonal matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

"13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)"

Clear["Global`*"]

n = 5;

(mat =
   ReplacePart[
    DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[A + W - EI, n]] +
     DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[-W', n - 1], 1] +
     DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[-W', n - 1], -1],
    {{1, 1} -> A - EI, {n, n} -> A - EI}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]